# CakePHP API Blackhole - validatePost disable not working?

Tags: php, api, cakephp, rest, ssl

We have recently shifted our application from http to https due to plain password logins via the API.

However, since doing so we are having real issues with Blackholes. Cake seems to black hole any 'POST' to the API function within our controller, despite

```
$this->Security->validatePost = false;
```

being set in AppController.php

We are using CakePHP version 2.1.3

Example of the code is as follows:

AppController.php:

```
function beforeFilter() 
{
    $this->Security->validatePost = false;  
    $this->Security->requireSecure(); 
}
```

SaleOrderController.php:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('addApi');   // Allow access to the API without logging in.
}
```

POSTing to this URL gives back the following message:
"The request has been black-holed"

Once we can get this working (without being blackholed) we will adjust it so that only certain actions may be performed with validatePost = false. However, for now we just want to get the system working.

Note: 'GET' requests to the action work fine (are not blackholed).

Am I missing some simple configuration here or is there some deeper issue at work? The security module seems a little scant on documentation and from my google searches it looks like most people have avoided blackholing by performing the same steps I have.

Comment: Cake Core has been updated to 2.2.2 however the issue is still arising. I have also tried disabling Security site-wide:
$this->Security->enabled = false;
However black-holing of https POST requests still exists.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out the following has no effect in CakePHP 2.X:

$this->Security->enabled = false;

To disable components you need to follow this doc:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html

My issue was related to CSRF protection which I believe may be new in CakePHP 2.X?
Anyway, All I needed to do was add the following line within my SaleOrderController beforeFilter function:

$this->Security->csrfCheck = false;

My whole BeforeFilter function is now:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('addApi');   // Allow access to the API without logging in.
    if (isset($this->Security) && $this->action == 'addApi') {
        $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
        $this->Security->validatePost = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I spent quite a bit of time on this, and your solution finally worked for me. I had also read the documents below and am correctly using `$this->Form->create();` and `$this->Form->end();`. Thanks for sharing your solution!

Comment: its a shame all the answers on SO amount to turning off security.  Security component is the weakest part of CakePHP unfortunatly

Answer (score 1):

See below URL

[CakePHP: Disable Security Component site wide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171227/cakephp-disable-security-component-site-wide)

[Disabling input elements in a CakePHP form that uses Security component and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670900/disabling-input-elements-in-a-cakephp-form-that-uses-security-component-and-jque)

http://life.mysiteonline.org/archives/175-Disable-the-Security-Component-in-CakePHP-only-for-Certain-Actions.html

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html

http://api.cakephp.org/class/security-component

**Or try it:-**

Even if you disable it in your app_controller your individual controller may have that security enabled.As my wild guess says this is what you want to do.If not let me know more about it

```
function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if(isset($this->Security) && $this->RequestHandler->isAjax() && $this->action = 'add'){

        $this->Security->enabled = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.
I don't want to disable security because I want to force the user to use HTTPS (which I believe is forced when security is enabled?) 
Also, disabling security seems to be a hammer approach to this issue - the issue is really with Form Validation, correct?

Comment: May be this issue is really with Form Validation. you can see these two url http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html http://api.cakephp.org/class/security-component for API

Comment: Thanks for your answer however this does not answer my question. I have read both of these documents however the information they offer do not fix my issue. I have also tried disabling Security globally in the AppController and requests are still black-holed - this is beginning to look like a CakePHP bug.